# c# sevenzipsharp- adding folder to new/existing archive

Tags: c#, compression, sevenzipsharp, create-directory

I have some code compressing folders/files:

```
      SevenZipCompressor compressor = new SevenZipCompressor();

                foreach (string listBoxItem in listBoxToCompress.Items)
                {
                    string choosenPath = listBoxItem;

                    int fileCount = Directory.GetFiles(listBoxItem).Length;
                    int folderCount = Directory.GetDirectories(listBoxItem).Length;

                    if (fileCount == 0 && folderCount == 0)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("folder " + listBoxItem + " is empty");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        listBox1.Items.Add("========================================");
                        listBox1.Items.Add("Compressing. "+listBoxItem+" Wait...");
                        listBox1.Refresh();
                        if (File.Exists(zipFile) == true)
                        {
                            compressor.CompressionMode = CompressionMode.Append;
                            compressor.ArchiveFormat = OutArchiveFormat.Zip;
                            compressor.CompressDirectory(choosenPath, zipFile);             
                            ++done;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            compressor.CompressionMode = CompressionMode.Create;
                            compressor.ArchiveFormat = OutArchiveFormat.Zip;
                            compressor.CompressDirectory(choosenPath, zipFile);             
                            ++done;
                        }
                        listBox1.Items.Add("Done.");
                        listBox1.Refresh();
                    }
                }
```

As You can see, i'm taking folders from listbox. For ex. i'm adding some folders to compress to one file.zip so my listbox is looks like:

```
+c:/test
+d:/somefolder
```

full structure is:

```
 +c:/test
 |--c:/test/testfile.exe
 |--c:/test/testfolder

 d:/somefolder
 |--d:/somefile.exe
```

But now, after compression, my archive is looks like:

```
 +archive.zip
 |--testfile.exe
 |--testfolder
 |--somefile.exe
```

How to create this overriding folder. I want archive looks like:

```
 +archive.zip
 |-test
   |----testfile.exe
   |----testfolder
 |-somefolder
   |----somefile.exe
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... i should add this line:

```
 compressor.PreserveDirectoryRoot = true;
```

This option is disabled by default, after enable- problem magically solved :)